# What is this 'sparky thing' in The Old Republic 'Deceived' trailer?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

During the brief (but eventful) fight with Malgus in the Jedi Temple, his jedi opponent charges him at some point near the end of it. To that, Malgus responds with something I'm not sure I'm able to identify. It looks like some sparks came out of his lightsaber and the jedi had to dodge it.

It's around 2:49 on the [official YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdgmH9Vv2-I):

[image]

So my question is: **what is it?** A force ability? Something lightsaber-related?

Never player TOR so maybe it's explained there.

Comment: Seems like a visual glitch, that the red and green lightsabre were supposed to collide there, but they changed their mind and forgot to remove the colliding visual effect.

Comment: How were they supposed to collide if the buys are like 3m away?

Comment: You see the sith swing and the jedi dodge, perhaps in an ealrier version of the trailer they were closer together.

Comment: That or a piece of metal was supposed to be thrown and Malgus is slicing through it.  Definitely an animation mistake.